# Fully duplicate mouse movement into touch event

Tags: windows-8, touch, tablet, pixelsense, wpf-4.0

I recently bought an Acer Iconia W510. All the touch events work fine, 1-finger click, double click etc. I have a windows application (WPF 4) that runs on a touch table (running windows 7, developed with pixelsense 2.0). I understand that there is no direct compatibility with windows 8. The application has a few buttons and a map where you are able to pan around. There are also a few clickable buttons. All these functions work with the mouse (left click) but not with a touch event. Is there a way / hack of copying the mouse movement to a touch event? In that way I am able to use touch to pan around.

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to recompile the application and put everything in a System.Windows Window, instead of a SurfaceWindow.

A slightly more complicated solution would be to put everything in a UserControl and add a System.Windows Window, next to the SurfaceWindow. Then in App.xaml.cs add something like this in the OnStartUp event:

```
if (Microsoft.Surface.SurfaceEnvironment.IsSurfaceEnvironmentAvailable)
                StartupUri = new Uri("SurfaceWindow.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            else
                StartupUri = new Uri("PlainWindow.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

I found this on the net somewhere and unfortunately can't remember the source, but for me it works like a charm.